# Questions about docker -v not working --> /srv/monero/chain:/home/monero/.bitmonero

Tags: docker, dockerfile, monero

### Dockerfile

https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/master/Dockerfile

### When I execute the following command

```
docker run -it --restart always --name monero -v /srv/monero/chain:/home/monero/.bitmonero -v /srv/monero/wallet:/wallet --privileged=true monero
```

> Exception in main! boost::filesystem::create_directory: Permission denied: "/home/monero/.bitmonero/lmdb"

### Next, I added -u root:root

```
docker run -it -u root:root --restart always --name monero -v /srv/monero/chain:/home/monero/.bitmonero -v /srv/monero/wallet:/wallet --privileged=true monero
```

> successful

### But there are no files in the `/srv/monero/chain` directory

### I think this is a problem I have with docker, I am a docker newbie and it has nothing to do with monero

### Additional Information

```
root@HEY13233121:~# docker run -it -d -u root --restart always --name monero --network net-1 --network-alias monero -v /srv/monero/chain:/home/monero/.bitmonero -v /srv/monero/wallet:/wallet -v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro --privileged=true monero
8e0a63230adf3ead036360e3662b00c95085776791eebab44d87a8123fff09d8
root@HEY13233121:~# docker exec -it monero bash
root@8e0a63230adf:/# ll
total 80
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Mar 26 05:24 ./
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Mar 26 05:24 ../
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root    0 Mar 26 05:24 .dockerenv*
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Jan 14 10:45 bin/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Apr 12  2016 boot/
drwxr-xr-x  13 root root 3760 Mar 26 05:24 dev/
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Mar 26 05:24 etc/
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Mar 25 23:46 home/
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Sep 13  2015 lib/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Jan 14 10:44 lib64/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Jan 14 10:43 media/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Jan 14 10:43 mnt/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Jan 14 10:43 opt/
dr-xr-xr-x 250 root root    0 Mar 26 05:24 proc/
drwx------   1 root root 4096 Mar 26 05:24 root/
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Jan 14 10:44 run/
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Mar 25 18:33 sbin/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Jan 14 10:43 srv/
dr-xr-xr-x  13 root root    0 Mar 25 23:58 sys/
drwxrwxrwt   1 root root 4096 Mar 25 23:46 tmp/
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Jan 14 10:43 usr/
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Jan 14 10:45 var/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Mar 26 01:16 wallet/
root@8e0a63230adf:/# cd home/
root@8e0a63230adf:/home# ll
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 1 root   root   4096 Mar 25 23:46 ./
drwxr-xr-x 1 root   root   4096 Mar 26 05:24 ../
drwxr-xr-x 3 monero monero 4096 Mar 25 23:46 monero/
root@8e0a63230adf:/home# cd monero/
root@8e0a63230adf:/home/monero# ll
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 3 monero monero 4096 Mar 25 23:46 ./
drwxr-xr-x 1 root   root   4096 Mar 25 23:46 ../
drwxr-xr-x 2 root   root   4096 Mar 26 01:16 .bitmonero/
root@8e0a63230adf:/home/monero# cd .bitmonero/
root@8e0a63230adf:/home/monero/.bitmonero# ll
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root   root   4096 Mar 26 01:16 ./
drwxr-xr-x 3 monero monero 4096 Mar 25 23:46 ../
```

Comment: Try run the container with command like `tail -f /dev/null` and then `exec` into the container to see if user `monero` has enough perms to `/home/monero` to do anything.

Comment: I can't get inside the container

Comment: Do you know how to log in to that?

Comment: I used ```docker exec -it monero bash```

Comment: Sorry, I got into the container

Comment: As usual default `home` directory of newly created users are located in `/home`, I think this user should have full access at `/home/monero`. Check if it's right.

Comment: If I don't add ```-u root``` when I start docker, the container will not be created properly, when I add ```-u root``` I successfully get inside the container by ```docker exec -it monero bash```, at this time I found that ```/home/monero``` belongs to ```user: monero```, but all subdirectories belong to ```user: root```

Comment: Can you remove `--privileged=true` when running container and then try again?

Comment: @Saeed Finished trying and the result is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### step 1:

```
docker run -it -u root --rm -v /srv/monero/chain:/home/monero/.bitmonero -v /srv/monero/wallet:/wallet -v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro --entrypoint=/bin/chown monero -R monero:monero /home/monero/.bitmonero
```

#### step 2:

```
docker run -itd --restart always --name monero --network net-1 --network-alias monero -v /srv/monero/chain:/home/monero/.bitmonero -v /srv/monero/wallet:/wallet -v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro --privileged=true monero
```